# how to get output for junit test in git actions steps

Tags: salesforce, github-actions

I'm new to git actions and was wondering if the following is possible. I'm running a junit test that is creating a salesforce record and returning the record Id, I would like to save the Id from the test log output and send it to to slack. Wondering if its possible to set the record Id as a variable create another job to send it to slack?

this is my workflow for creating the record
test:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Set up JDK 14
    uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: 14
      cache: maven

  - name: Build project with Maven
    run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml -Dtest="StageSFDCTestData#insertNewAccountTwo"
```